# What do we mean by this the charge on a body is denoted by $q$?

Tags: electrostatics, charge

I am sorry if this is a silly question, we know that electric charge is a characteristic property of a subatomic particle. And, a body is electrically charged by the transfer of electrons.

Then, what does it mean by "the charge on a body is denoted by $q$"? What are we talking about here? Are we denoting this property by $q$? Also, what does it mean when we say a body has charge $+2\text{ C}$? What does $+2\text{ C}$ have to do with the property electric charge?

Answer (score 2):

Charge was measured on macroscopic bodies a long time before the discovery  of subatomic particles, and the unit of measurement is the [Coulomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coulomb)

> The coulomb (symbol: C) is the International System of Units (SI) unit of electric charge. Under *the 2019 redefinition* of the SI base units, which took effect on 20 May 2019, the coulomb is exactly $1/(1.602176634×10^{−19})$ elementary charges. The same number of electrons has the same magnitude but opposite sign of charge, that is, a charge of −1 C.

italics mine

Comment: please tell me am I right here ?
So, Basically this line-->"the charge on a body" means the amount of charge on a body or the numeric value of charge on a body. Right ?
Suppose a body has the property of Electric Charge and we intend to measure this property.So, by saying this line-->"the charge on a body" we mean that we are talking about the amount of charge on a body or the numeric value of charge on a body.
And after measuring this propety ,We denote this amount of charge(numeric value) by q.

Comment: We mean how many coulombs is the charge on the body, q=so-many coulombs